# Git - VS2013 and Win10 w/posh git won't add .sln

Tags: git

I'm hoping this is something simple I've overlooked.

I'm using a combo of posh-git command line and VS2013 git.

This

```
git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD
```

Does not show the .sln.

I tried (and have in the past successfully used)

```
git add "MyApp.sln"
```

However, that's not adding anything now.  My prompt with posh git status shows

```
[master ≡]>
```

after my attempted add.  In addition commit doesn't see anything to commit, either on the command line or from VS.

Comment: What does `git status --ignored` show?

Comment: This is very odd to me:  I "solved" this late last night when I was documenting my failure and copied my ls-tree... output to a file.  I searched the file and there was the .sln.   My Powershell search (multiple) had failed to find it.  I just now logged on with the same failed result.  Then I selected text and searched in PS and PS found it.  I'll call this one pilot error (although I have no idea what's up  - now at least I know how to check it thoroughly).